# How to make widget button which can be used in multiple choice question?

Tags: flutter

I made a customizable button which can have a different function, title, and color. But the problem is whenever I click on one button, it changes the color of all the buttons using that color property. I want them to have their initial color and change when pressed, similar to quiz buttons where it changes its color when correct or wrong.

Below is my code.

```dart
buildQuizButton(
      {String text,
      Color backgroundColor,
      Color textColor,
      Color borderColor,
      Function function}) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: function,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: backgroundColor,
              border: Border.all(color: borderColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(text,
              style: TextStyle(color: textColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          width: 250.0,
          height: 35.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```dart
buildQuizAnswerButton(String option) {
    if (hasAnswered) {
      if (isCorrect) {
        return buildQuizButton(
          text: option,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFaed581),
          textColor: Colors.black,
          borderColor: Color(0xFFaed581),
        );
      } else if (!isCorrect) {
        return buildQuizButton(
          text: option,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFff1744),
          textColor: Colors.black,
          borderColor: Color(0xFFff1744),
        );
      }
    } else if (!hasAnswered) {
      return buildQuizButton(
        text: option,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFaf3e5f5),
        textColor: Colors.black,
        borderColor: Colors.black,
        function: checkAnswer(option),
      );
    }
}
```

```dart
checkAnswer(String option) {
    if (option == quizAnswer) {
      if (ownerId == currentUserId) {
        setState(() {
          hasAnswered = true;
          isCorrect = true;
        });
        inactiveFunction(10);
      } else if (ownerId != currentUserId) {
        setState(() {
          hasAnswered = true;
          isCorrect = true;
        });
        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) {
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('all_quizes')
              .document(quizId)
              .updateData({
            'players': FieldValue.increment(1),
          });
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('user')
              .document(currentUserId)
              .updateData({'correctAnswered': FieldValue.increment(1)});
        }).then((val) {
          inactiveFunction(60);
        });
      }
    } else if (option != quizAnswer) {
      if (ownerId == currentUserId) {
        setState(() {
          hasAnswered = true;
          isCorrect = false;
        });
        inactiveFunction(10);
      } else if (ownerId != currentUserId) {
        setState(() {
          hasAnswered = true;
          isCorrect = false;
        });
        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) {
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('all_quizes')
              .document(quizId)
              .updateData({
            'players': FieldValue.increment(1),
          });
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('user')
              .document(currentUserId)
              .updateData({'wrongAnswered': FieldValue.increment(1)});
        }).then((val) {
          inactiveFunction(60);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

The above code doesn't work at all. It shows red color already before pressed.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [`Radio`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html) button.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. You solved my problem. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Radio`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html), which is a Material button that does what you want.

[Here](https://grokonez.com/flutter/flutter-radio-button-example) is an example of how to use it.